# Bold Fonts in Google Chrome are Blurry (@Font-Face)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

Recently after upgrading my Google Chrome browser to `Version 32.0.1700.76 m` I noticed that bold fonts have a blur/drop shadow effect on my sites using `@font-face`.

[**Here is an example site with bold text**](http://archant.co.uk/careers/vacancies).

[image]

[**Here is an example site with bold headers**](http://www.planningfinder.co.uk/).

[image]

Before updating my Chrome these sites were displaying font correctly, I have tested fonts in the following browsers and they are still displaying correctly:

- Firefox 26.0
- IE11
- Opera 12.11
- Safari 5.1.7

Is there any way to stop this blur effect other than downgrading Google Chrome?

**EDIT**

I sent a error report to Google about this issue and it seems like they have reverted the "blurry" effect on fonts. To avoid this issue go with **Jukka K. Korpela's** solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the examples, you have declared only normal (regular) typefaces for Gotham and Sansation in `@font-face` rules, yet try to use bold face. This makes browsers apply algorithmic (synthetic) bolding, with varying results.

The solution is to get bold typefaces and declare them, in `@font-face` rules that have `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: This is the solution. Weird that it has only started happening after I updated chrome. These sites have been live for over a year with no issues. Its a shame the bold font type is... too bold. Thanks.

Comment: I sent a error report to Google about this issue and it seems like they have reverted the "blurry" effect on fonts :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332958 The issue is closed for comments and appears as "fixed" however it is not. I'm running latest version 34 and bold fonts are sill blurry, even on the Chrome Web Store site...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The question was asked almost 5 years back, but the problem still persists. I am using Chrome 69.

In my project when google font is used I got blurry text.

I use the google font via below code :

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,600,800'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

And the most important part in font-weight properties I always use

> font-weight: bold

**Solution:** Now if you use 400,600,800 as normal, semi-bold and bold, of course then replace it with

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:light,regular,medium,thin,italic,mediumitalic,bold'
>   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Note: I am sharing a solution which solved my issue. It may not apply to your situation.