# Font weight bold show blurry in crome browser

Tags: html, css

Please help me in this image see how font area showing very blurry in Chrome browser.

`font-weight: normal` looks good, only when i use `font-weight: bold` it appears blurry.

[image]

Comment: please, add code snippet to see what's happening on there. Check that you've latest Chrome version, then check if the font that you charged are bold-capable or you're forcing to it. Cheers!

Comment: I'm afraid this is caused by Chrome's font rendering. Have you tried different font sizes, maybe a rounded number in pixels? Also, does the same occur in other browsers?

Comment: what font-family do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bold Fonts in Google Chrome are Blurry (@Font-Face)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332475/bold-fonts-in-google-chrome-are-blurry-font-face)

Comment: thanks there was antialising issue @JoëlBonetRodríguez